# What can `Nothing` be used for?

Tags: kotlin, types, kotlin-null-safety

I am specifically asking for the **non-nullable** type `Nothing`.

I do know that `Nothing?` allows us to, for example, filter `null` to make an overload unambiguous, but I'm struggling to think of instances where `Nothing` would be useful.

`Nothing?` can have exactly one value, `null`. So `Nothing` can have exactly no value. What's the point? Why not simply use `Unit`?

Comment: The official docs have something to say on it: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#the-nothing-type

Comment: The answer of Willi below is a great answer. 

Some math, if you're interested: 
`Nothing` is a type that has no values, it's an empty set. The empty-set (`Nothing`) is a sub-set of *all* other sets (types). That is why a `Nothing` type is assignable to all other types ==> `Nothing` is a sub-class of all other types. 

The `?` means "or-null". That's why the type `Nothing?` has one value: `null` (empty-set + `null`).

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston Great to see it from that perspective :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. `Nothing` is the counterpart to `Any?`

Just as `Any?` is the base type of any other type, `Nothing` is the sub type of any other type (even the nullable ones).

Knowing this it becomes clear that `s` will be of type `String` in the following example, given name is a `String?`.

```
val s = name ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Name required")
```

The `throw` expression returns `Nothing`, and the common base type of `String` and `Nothing` is `String`. That's what we want, because that's the type we want to work with.

If we would use `Unit` instead of `Nothing` the common base type would be `Any`, which is certainly not what we want, because it would require a cast to `String` afterward.

That makes sense too, because if the exception will be thrown execution cannot continue there, thus `s` wouldn't be used any further anyway.

### 2. `Nothing` marks code locations that can never be reached

```
fun foo() {
   throw IllegalArgumentException("...")
   println("Hey") // unreachable code
}
```

### 3. Type inference

If `null` is used to initialize a value of an inferred type and there's no other information to determine a more specific type, the inferred type will be `Nothing?`.

```
val x = null           // 'x' has type `Nothing?`
val l = listOf(null)   // 'l' has type `List<Nothing?>
```

[Further reading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#the-nothing-type)

Comment: Thank you. Small correction: `Any?` is the supertype of ALL types, nullable or not, and `Nothing` (not `Nothing?`) is the subtype of ALL types, nullable or not. It doesn't make sense to regard nullable and non-nullable types as two separate things as your footnote suggests.

Comment: @User1291 Sry if my answer is not clear enough. Here is what I mean: Any is the supertype of all non-nullable types and Any? is the supertype of ALL types. The same applies in analogy to Nothing/Nothing? but as subtype. Take a look here: https://pl.kotl.in/SoUPnvW6E So the distinction makes sense.

Comment: I understood you the first time. You're still wrong when you say "`Nothing?` is the subtype of any other type". `Nothing?` is the subtype of all **nullable** types. `Nothing` is the subtype of all non-nullable types AND a subtype of `Nothing?` and therefore the subtype of all other types, nullable or not.

Answer (score 0):

`Nothing` is used to tell the compiler that it will never return. For example,

```
fun main() {
   var name: String? = null
   val notNullName = name ?: fail("name was null")
   println(notNullName)
}

fun fail(message: String): Nothing {
  throw RuntimeException(message)
}

fun infiniteLoop(): Nothing {
   while (true) {
     // Nothingness
   }
}
```

Comment: And what value does "telling the compiler that it will never return" bring? (Other than for type inference, obviously.)